# Adding strikethrough table row when have horizontal scrollbar

Tags: html, css

I am adding strikethrough table row, but its showing only till table horizontal scrollbar not after the scrollbar come.

how to show strike line 100% of the scroll i can not add background image because there is already background image in the table rows.

is there any otherway to fix this issue.

My code

```css
.TableWrap{
  overflow: auto;
  position: relative;
}

.strike{
  position: relative;
}

.strike:after {
    content: "";
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    width: 100%;
    height: 4px;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 111;
    left: 0;
    margin-top: 40px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
  <div class="TableWrap">
  <table class="table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>#</th>
        <th>Table heading</th>
        <th>Table heading</th>
        <th>Table heading</th>
        <th>Table heading</th>
        <th>Table heading</th>
        <th>Table heading</th>
        <th>Table heading</th>
        <th>Table heading</th>
        <th>Table heading</th>
        <th>Table heading</th>
        <th>Table heading</th>
        <th>Table heading</th>
        <th>Table heading</th>
        <th>Table heading</th>
        <th>Table heading</th>
        <th>Table heading</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <th >1</th>
        <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
        <td>Table cell</td>
        <td>Table cell</td>
        <td>Table cell</td>
        <td>Table cell</td>
        <td>Table cell</td>
        <td>Table cell</td>
        <td>Table cell</td>
        <td>Table cell</td>
        <td>Table cell</td>
        <td>Table cell</td>
        <td>Table cell</td>
        <td>Table cell</td>
        <td>Table cell</td>
        <td>Table cell</td>
        <td>Table cell</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="strike">
        <th>2</th>
        <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
        <td>Table cell</td>
        <td>Table cell</td>
        <td>Table cell</td>
        <td>Table cell</td>
        <td>Table cell</td>
        <td>Table cell</td>
        <td>Table cell</td>
        <td>Table cell</td>
        <td>Table cell</td>
        <td>Table cell</td>
        <td>Table cell</td>
        <td>Table cell</td>
        <td>Table cell</td>
        <td>Table cell</td>
        <td>Table cell</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>3</th>
        <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
        <td>Table cell</td>
        <td>Table cell</td>
        <td>Table cell</td>
        <td>Table cell</td>
        <td>Table cell</td>
        <td>Table cell</td>
        <td>Table cell</td>
        <td>Table cell</td>
        <td>Table cell</td>
        <td>Table cell</td>
        <td>Table cell</td>
        <td>Table cell</td>
        <td>Table cell</td>
        <td>Table cell</td>
        <td>Table cell</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

These kind of approaches to styling will become difficult to maintain in the long run.

Howbeit, you can give your `TableWrap` class the style of `display:inline-block`, and adjust the strikea a little bit by a negative margin value.

You can read more about layouts [here](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-display-3/)